# How to check in component.html if column type=1 display label text Active else display Not active?

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, angular-directive, angular-components

I have object name ReportControl I face issue I cannot check value related to this object

if have column type 1 then display label active else display label not active on reportcomponent.html

data of object ReportControl as below

```
{"reportId":2028,"fieldName":"offilneURL","reportStatus":"HiddenColumn","columnType":1}
```

on reportcomponent.ts

```
this._displayreport.GetReportControl(param2).subscribe((res: any) => {
        this.ReportControl = res;
        console.log("report control is" + JSON.stringify(this.ReportControl) );

      });
```

on service.ts

```
  GetReportControl(id : string){
      return this.http.get<any[]>(this.url+ 'report/GetAllReportControl/id=' + id)
      .map(res=>res);

    }
```

reportcomponent.html

I need to check if column type = 1 then display label with text active
else display label with text not active .

Expected result display label with text active

Comment: Could you please also add `html` too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you display text conditionally in html, Is this what you expect ?

```
<label>{{ReportControl.columnType == 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}}</label>
```

Using `*ngIf`

```
<label *ngIf="ReportControl.columnType == 1">Active</label>
<label *ngIf="ReportControl.columnType == 0">Inactive</label>
```

Comment: can i do that using *ngIf